# How to fit a 3D curve data without model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, curve-fitting

I have a scatter curved data in 3D `z=f(x,y)`, I want to fit it a smoothed curve. The fitted curve needs to be able to be extracted points from.

I don't have a model for it and I don't bother to make a model. I was thinking use `polyfit` but it seems only to work for 2D data. I have seen an answer that suggests to make one variable as independent and generate the other two w.r.t it, let's say x. I don't think it is a good idea as the relation between y and z is ignored.

I tried using `scipy.interpolate.splprep`. I later realised it was spline not fitting.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


tck, u = interpolate.splprep([xdata,ydata,zdata], s=2)
x,y,z = interpolate.splev(u,tck)

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax3d = fig1.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax3d.plot(xdata,ydata,zdata, 'bo')
ax3d.plot(x,y,z, 'r-')
```

Is there a way to make interpolate.splprep smoother? Or any other method to fit a 3D curve?

**Edit**
I have managed to make the curve smoother by increase quite a bit of s.
The x,y,z given by splev are distributed unevenly like the original data. How can I extract a even spread data from the smoothed curve.
Or I mean how I can get the smoothed spline model by splprep, I can np.linspace x and y then sub to the model and get a smoothed data set.

This is my data.
[A curve](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zr7bS5WOXgNJOywCGxYBzX4dXMVJXM62/view?usp=sharing)

[Fitting a polynomial using np.polyfit in 3 dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350891/fitting-a-polynomial-using-np-polyfit-in-3-dimensions)
Follow the second answer of this question, I managed to get a coefficient result by `sklearn`. But I don't know how to use it. How can I used it to get the smoothed data?

I am frustrating not able to find a way plot or extract data from it.

Comment: There's no such thing as "fitting a curve without a model". Whatever function or method you use to interpolate between the original data points, that's your model - in the case of `splprep` the model is a set of splines. You just need to choose a model that suits your needs. Have you tried adjusting the [parameters of splprep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html)?

Comment: @nekomatic  Thank you for your comment, I did flip a bit at my first attempt. After your remind, I tried a bigger range of parameter s in my data. It appears to improve when s is 6e12 in my case. By the way, how can I extract arbitrary 
points from the output of splev?

Comment: I think you want to use [splev](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html#scipy.interpolate.splev).

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data? I will run it through my web site's 3D surface "function finder" and see if it can find a smooth surface equation that is fits the data well.